# Can't make sense out of this Perl code

Tags: perl

This snippet basically reads a file line by line, which looks something like:

```
Album=In Between Dreams
Interpret=Jack Johnson
Titel=Better Together
Titel=Never Know
Titel=Banana Pancakes
Album=Pictures
Interpret=Katie Melua
Titel=Mary Pickford
Titel=It's All in My Head
Titel=If the Lights Go Out
Album=All the Lost Souls
Interpret=James Blunt
Titel=1973
Titel=One of the Brightest Stars
```

So it somehow connects the "Interpreter" with an album and this album with a list of titles. But what I don't quite get is how:

```
while ($line = <IN>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /=/) {
        ($name, $wert) = split(/=/, $line);
    }
    else {
        next;
    }
    if ($name eq "Album") {
        $album = $wert;
    }
    if ($name eq "Interpret") {
        $interpret = $wert;
        $cd{$interpret}{album} = $album; // assigns an album to an interpreter?
        $titelnummer = 0;
    }
    if ($name eq "Titel") {
        $cd{$interpret}{titel}[$titelnummer++] = $wert; // assigns titles to an interpreter - WTF? how can this work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop keeps running and putting the current line into `$line` as long as there are new lines in the file handle `<IN>`. `chomp` removes the newline at the end of every row.

`split` splits the line into two parts on the equal sign (`/=/` is a *regular expression*) and puts the first part in `$name` and the second part in `$wert`.

`%cd` is a hash that contains references to other hashes. The first "level" is the name of interpreter.

(Please ask more specific questions if you still do not understand.)

Comment: That's the easy part, what I don't get is how the hash gets filled.

Comment: @Helper: The script remembers the last interpreter and album between loops since those variables are not scoped. Please be more specific.

Comment: @HelperMethod: for each "Titel" line, the array of titles within the hash for that interpreter is added to.  Tracking `$titelnummer` is a horrible kludge; using `push` would be much more elegant.

Comment: Yes, please don't get any ideas about how to write code from this example!

Comment: Agree! code like this gives Perl a bad name. Perl is a 'with great power comes great responsibility' type of language, extremely powerful, fun and fast, but can get you into trouble if you try to hack it without thought (but what language doesnt?)

Comment: Although this code makes a few foolish mistakes (like using `$titlenummer` instead of `push`), I would say that otherwise it represents the clearest and most correct way of dealing with the file format given.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is a hash of hashes.
`$cd{$interpret}{album}` contains album for interpreter.

`$cd{$interpret}{titel}` contains an array of Titel, which is filled incrementally in the last `if`.

Perl is a very concise language.

Comment: <strike>concise</strike> obtuse -- There, FTFY ;)

Comment: @Adam Robinson, I don't think you mean [obtuse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obtuse) "1. not quick or alert in perception, feeling, or intellect; not sensitive or observant; dull." but instead [oblique](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oblique) "5. indirectly stated or expressed; not straightforward" or "6. indirectly aimed at or reached, as ends or results; deviously achieved." I'd agree that the OP's code is oblique, I don't see how it could be obtuse, and Perl as a language does not have to be either.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: http://english.stackexchange.com/ -- Nonetheless, yes, I hastily wrote obtuse when I meant oblique. In any case, Perl does not have to be so, but it usually is.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to figure out what's going on is to inspect the data structure.  After the while loop, temporarily insert this code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print '%cd ', Dumper \%cd;
exit;
```

This may have a large output if the input is large.